# Initiating an instance of PopupWindow as a class from a fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, popupwindow

I've been getting a null pointer exception when I try and call showPopup2 from FirstFragment. This is my ShowPopup class,

```
public class ShowPopup extends Activity {
public void showPopup2(View v) {
    Button btnDismiss;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)showPopup.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, 580, 500, true); 
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 40);
    btnDismiss=(Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnDismissxml);
    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0){
        popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
}
```

and this is the fragment,

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
public static Context context;
Button btnPopup;
public ShowPopup ShowPopup;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedDataEntryInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedDataEntryInstanceState);
}

//@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater{   
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);   
    btnPopup = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnPopupxml);
    btnPopup.setOnClickListener(this);
    populateFirstFragment(v);
    return v;
}

//@Override
public void onViewCreated(View v) {
    btnPopup = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnPopupxml);
    btnPopup.setOnClickListener(this);
}

//@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        ShowPopup.showPopup2(v);
    } 
}
```

What is causing the null pointer exception? Is there a better way to structure this? My goal is to be able to (1) access this from other methods in my application as well as, (2) not have this method cluttering up my fragments.
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generally works,

**ShowPopup.java**

```
public class showPopup {
Context ctx;

public showPopup(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx; 
}

public void goJoe(View parent){
    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(ctx);
    LayoutParams para = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView tvMessage = new TextView(ctx);
    Button btnDismiss = new Button (ctx);

    tvMessage.setLayoutParams(para);
    tvMessage.setText("This is the popup window.");
    popup.setContentView(tvMessage);

    btnDismiss.findViewById(R.id.btnDismissxml);
    btnDismiss.setLayoutParams(para);
    btnDismiss.setWidth(120);
    btnDismiss.setHeight(20);
    btnDismiss.setText("Close popupWindow.java");
    popup.setContentView(btnDismiss);

    popup.setWidth(400);
    popup.setHeight(180);
    popup.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 10, 10);
    popup.update();

    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popup.dismiss();    
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**ThirdTab.java**

```
public class ThirdTab extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
Button btnPopup;
showPopup showPopup;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.thirdtab_fragment, container, false);    
    btnPopup = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnPopupxml);
    btnPopup.setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}

//@Override
public void onViewCreated(View v) {
    btnPopup = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnPopupxml);
    btnPopup.setOnClickListener(this);
}
//@Override
    @Override
    public void onClick(View parent) {
        new showPopup(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).goJoe(parent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared an instance of ShowPopup Activity in your FirstFragment, but have not initialized this which is causing null pointer when you call ShowPopup.showPopup2(v).
Also, an Activity should not be used like an Object to just call functions on it. You can put the showPopup2() function inside the FirstFragment itself.

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
public static Context context;
Button btnPopup;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedDataEntryInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedDataEntryInstanceState);
}

//@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater{   
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);   
btnPopup = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnPopupxml);
btnPopup.setOnClickListener(this);
populateFirstFragment(v);
return v;
}

//@Override
public void onViewCreated(View v) {
btnPopup = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnPopupxml);
btnPopup.setOnClickListener(this);
}

//@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    showPopup2(v);
} 

public void showPopup2(View v) {
Button btnDismiss;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, 580, 500, true); 
popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 40);
btnDismiss=(Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnDismissxml);
btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0){
    popupWindow.dismiss();
    }
});
}

}
```

Comment: I would strongly prefer to have showPopup() in a separate file. Any suggestions regarding the best way to do this? Thanks.